# SSMS - SSRS job returns after deletion

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-agent

we have several SSRS reports that we want to run at night.
Every time we create a subscription, SSRS creates a job with its own schedule and one step in the job
for example:

```
exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='ffe3a82d-367a-424c-8446-d2da0ce10666'
```

We have 5 reports. Therefore, there are 5 jobs. Instead of executing every single job, we want to combine all jobs into one. Meaning, one job with 5 steps. Therefore, we copy out the step command of each job (the above 'exec' snippet) and add it as an additional step to the main job.
Once this is done, we delete all 5 SSRS generated jobs.

The problem now is that once we restart the ReportServer services or the actual time of the original subscription schedule hits (default: 2am), all these 5 jobs are shown again in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). We can delete them but the next day, they are back again.

Any idea? We never had the problem in SQL 2008 R2 but with only with SQL 2014.

Comment: do they have the same eventdata every time the SSRS restarts?

Comment: Yes, the event data ID stays the same.

Comment: if it the event stays the same then i suppose you can delete the job with the same event data every restart of the server through sql agent.

Comment: Yes, however, the job even gets created at the default schedule run (2am). We now delete those jobs automatically. However, I don't understand why this behavior was introduced in SQL 2014. It was not there in 2008 R2